# Vector cross product in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: cross-product, cylindrical-coordinates

I need to calculate the cross product of two vectors given in cylindrical coordinates but i can't find the formula for it anywhere online. Is it expected that i find the formula myself or is there just no formula for it?

Comment: You need to use Levi civita symbols, metric tensors probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual formula holds in *any* right-handed orthonormal frame, in particular $(\mathbf{e}_r, \mathbf{e}_\phi, \mathbf{e}_z)$.